# Array.prototype.find, what's its spec?

Tags: javascript

Those who have Chrome 30.0.1599.14 dev seem to be gifted of this new function:

```
String(Array.prototype.find); // "function find() { [native code] }"
```

However, I haven't found any reference for this addition. From my tests it seems that it accepts arguments a-la `some`, `every` and so on:

```
array.some(callback[, thisObject]);
```

and `callback` is the usual callback function of that kind:

```
function([item[, index[, array]]]) {
   ...
}
```

The function is expected to return `true` when the "right" `item` is passed, so that item becomes the value returned by `find`. For example:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("*"))
        .find(function(element) {return element.id === "content";});
```

It's an odd way to re-define `document.getElementById`, except when the item isn't found `find` returns `undefined` instead of `null`.

It could be nice if this function could accept an initial index, or if there could be a dual function like `lastFind` that parses the array from the end.

Is there anybody who's already seen this function and can tell me where I can find its spec?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is ECMA Script 6. Here's an [HTML version of the ES6 spec](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html). Here's the [specific section for `Array.prototype.find()`](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-array.prototype.find).

**Update**: also, [the Chromium bug for Array.prototype.find implementation](https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=2776).

Comment: And this pretty much answer my question. Thank you.

Comment: Broken links?..